# Using correct terminology: What is a "class reference" versus a "class variable"?

Tags: c#, oop

In an effort to ensure the use of proper terminology when describing certain aspects of code, I'm asking for clarification of use in the following context:

If we write

```
int myIntTest;
```

we say "We have an `int` variable"

Assume that we have an Employee class, and when we write

```
Employee myObjectTest;
```

we say "We have a reference for an `Employee` object"

My question is:

Is it corret to say  "`myObjectTest` is a `Employee` class' variable"?

Comment: Employee class' variable means its somehow part of the Employee class, which is not true. myObjectTest is a variable that references the object (Employee). Until you initialize it, its just a null reference to an Employee class.

Comment: "`myObjectTest is a variable of type Employee`" would be more correct.

Comment: I'd avoid saying so because at least in other languages, the term "class variable" has a completely different meaning, different from what you intend here.

Comment: Whether or not the object is a value type or a reference type is irrelevant, they are both variables. Whether that variable points to a value or points to a reference, its still variable because it could change to a different value or reference as needed. The opposite to a variable would be a constant.

Comment: Note also that the title asks about the phrase "class variable" but in the question you ask about the phrase "class's variable".

Comment: `> Could we just as well say "myObjectTest is a Employee class' variable"?` --

nope. Variable stores objects, not classes themselves. Class is a somewhat a definition of an object. For reference types (which `Employee` most likely is) variable stores a pointer (reference) to an \***instance\*** of that class. Object itself is allocated and stored somewhere else in heap and variable keeps an address in memory to referenced object.

Comment: @TheBatman let's not get into the `const`ant variable discussion :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the decision to close this question. The terminology at issue is essential in the co0mmunication of relevant requirements and code development.

Comment: @DavidW I agree, the correct terminology is not an opinion, it's a fact.

Comment: I read The Book of Deitel&Deitel's Visual C# How to pogram 2012 . In Page 446 (Fig 12.1's 10-12 lines says):                                                                       //(comment:)assign base-class reference to base class variable                    
 (code:)ComEmploye comsionEmploye= new CommissionEmployee(...............)                       The comment confused me

Comment: @MahmoodGaribov I could see how that could be confusing. Lets consider the statement `Foo foo = new Foo()`. In this example, `foo` is the *variable*, whereas `new Foo()` is the *reference* that is being assigned to it.

Comment: @CaiusJard lol thats probably a good idea! The term `variable` has come to be more generally applied to any non-literal value, but in the strictest sense a `variable` should be, well, *variable*. I wouldn't consider a constant a variable strictly by the definition, but it is in common use to refer to one as such.

Comment: Maybe `var` will help clear up the variable/constant naming laziness, in time :) At least our Foo foo (which incidentally is the name my friend's child uses for vagina) has different case; those VB perverts can get away with Dim Foo as Foo and what's worse- the Windows forms designer does it by default so sometimes Form1.Whatever is a static reference and other times an instance one :/

Comment: I have modified the title of this question and made slight edits to its content to encourage a possible reopen of this question. This is a legitimate topic that I believe goes beyond the scope of opinion and merits further discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually say "myObjectTest is a variable of type Employee" or if I want to be very specific "myObjectTest is a variable referencing an Employee instance (or `null`)".

I'm not sure if there's one definitive answer. Maybe somebody knows and can point you to the correct section of the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) :)

Here's what I found:

> ## Types
>
> Value types differ from reference types in that variables of the value types directly contain their data, whereas variables of the reference types store references to their data, the latter being known as objects.

and

> ## Variables
>
> Variables represent storage locations. Every variable has a type that determines what values can be stored in the variable.

So it seems like that the C# spec talks about a variable having a type. Thus, "myObjectTest is a variable of type Employee" matches the spec's language.

Comment: You're perfectly capable of reading the specification; you don't need me to do it!

Comment: @EricLippert: I can read it, yes, but I don't know it well enough to (efficiently) find the part where this is explained – if it is explained. I've seen many well-written answers from you in the past where you pinpoint and quote even small sidenotes from the spec :) Sorry if I offended you by making this statement

Comment: The specification begins with a table of contents to help you pinpoint the appropriate section; soft copies are keyword searchable; the hard-copy published version of the spec ends with a keyword index. That's how I navigate the specification quickly. I don't have some super power.

Comment: I am not *offended*, but I am *opposed to the narrative that the specification is only accessible by a priesthood*. I worked hard to ensure that the specification could be used by any interested party; I encourage you to do so without getting me involved.

Comment: @EricLippert: sorry, that was not my intention either (non-native speaker here, so I could have possibly phrased that sentence better in my answer). I know the spec available online to everybody. But before pointing to the wrong section of the spec, I thought I'd let the people who know it well do that. Sure, misinformation in an answer would get downvoted or corrected eventually, but better not have the wrong info there in the first place.

Comment: I've now added the part of the spec which I believe are the correct ones to back up my claim and have added a link. Sorry again if my intention came across wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For the variable itself I would say it's "A variable of type Employee":

```
//"variable of type Employee" or
//"employee variable"
Employee e;
```

If an instance of the Employee class has been assigned to it I would probably say it's "an Employee instance":

```
//"employee instance e"
e = new Employee("John", "Smith", "Manager");
```

In general conversation terms between e.g. two developers you'll tend to find that the variable, as a placeholder, typically fades in importance compared to the data it holds. You might talk about variables `employeeA` and `employeeB` but what you'll actually be talking about are the Employee instances assigned to those variables - "why do employeeA and employeeB have the same name and role? Hmmm. Oh look, they're pointing to the same instance"

If you're saying something is a class variable it's a bit vague, but would probably be interpreted as "a class wide variable" - a variable that is a data member of the class. It may be best to avoid the phrase and instead use the same terms that the documentation uses for those (fields, properties, methods, constructors etc are all class members). If you're determined to use "variable" don't mention "class" - just say "Employee variable" as in "the constructor uses two Employee variables". If you're talking about variables in the specification of a method, call them parameters or arguments or say that the method "takes (class name)" - "the constructor has two Employee arguments" or "this method takes an array of Employees"

Answer (score 0):

As stated, no - `myObjectTest` represents a variable intended to hold a reference to an instance of `Employee`. To say "Employee class' variable" implies a variable that *belongs* to the `Employee` class, not one that *represents an instance* of the class.